# passing <string> to string is causing error

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this function

```
    static async Task<string> ChatGPT(string token, string model, string message)
    {
        ChatGPTClient chatGPTClient = new ChatGPTClient();
        string result = await chatGPTClient.GetChatGPTResponse(token, model, message);
        return result;
    }
```

result is a string inside the function and passed when it called

when i debug i can read the value of `result = "Hello! How can I assist you today?"`

calling it from this event

```
    private void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string token = txtToken.Text;
        string model = cmbModel.Text;
        string message = txtPrompt.Text;

        txtDisplay.text = ChatGPT(token, model, message).ToString();
    }
```

but the value of **txtDisplay** is

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.String,APIApp.frmChatGPT+<ChatGPT>d__1]
```

what am i doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: try this `txtDisplay.text = ChatGPT(token, model, message).Result.ToString();`

Comment: no, this returns nothing in the textbox!

Comment: maybe you meant `txtDisplay.text = await ChatGPT(token, model, message);` ?  But you will need to make your click handler async as well.  The original code is trying to inspect a synchronization object (the Task),  not actually processing the task and getting its result

Comment: that's quite the same that using .Result, i don't know why it returned empty for you, strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result type of the `ChatGPT` method is `Task<string>`. If you want to assign the string result from the task then you have to `await` the task.

```cs
private async void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string token = txtToken.Text;
    string model = cmbModel.Text;
    string message = txtPrompt.Text;

    txtDisplay.text = await ChatGPT(token, model, message);
}
```

You can read more about `async`/`await` at the [blog from Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).